# bspwm switching monitors doesn't work

Tags: window-manager

Any ideas why switching monitors with

```
super + {_,shift + }{1-9,0}
```

doesn't work until after I run this line in my terminal:

```
bspc monitor -d 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 bspc query -T
```

Here is my .conf/bspwm/bspwmrc

```
#! /bin/sh

sxhkd &

bspc monitor -d 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

bspc config border_width         2
bspc config window_gap          12

bspc config split_ratio          0.52
bspc config borderless_monocle   true
bspc config gapless_monocle      true
bspc config focus_by_distance    true
bspc config history_aware_focus  true

bspc rule -a Gimp desktop='^8' state=floating follow=on
bspc rule -a Chromium desktop='^2'
bspc rule -a mplayer2 state=floating
bspc rule -a Kupfer.py focus=on
bspc rule -a Screenkey manage=off
```

Here is my .conf/sxhkd/sxhkdrc:

```
#
# wm independent hotkeys
#

# terminal emulator
super + Return
        termite 

# program launcher
super + space
        rofi -show run

# make sxhkd reload its configuration files:
super + Escape
    pkill -USR1 -x sxhkd

#
# bspwm hotkeys
#

# quit bspwm normally
super + alt + Escape
    bspc quit

# close and kill
super + {_,shift + }w
    bspc node -{c,k}

# alternate between the tiled and monocle layout
super + m
    bspc desktop -l next

# if the current node is automatic, send it to the last manual, otherwise pull the last leaf
super + y
    bspc query -N -n focused.automatic && bspc node -n last.!automatic || bspc node last.leaf -n focused

# swap the current node and the biggest node
super + g
    bspc node -s biggest

#
# state/flags
#

# set the window state
super + {t,shift + t,s,f}
    bspc node -t {tiled,pseudo_tiled,floating,fullscreen}

# set the node flags
super + ctrl + {x,y,z}
    bspc node -g {locked,sticky,private}

#
# focus/swap
#

# focus the node in the given direction
super + {_,shift + }{h,j,k,l}
    bspc node -{f,s} {west,south,north,east}

# focus the node for the given path jump
super + {p,b,comma,period}
    bspc node -f @{parent,brother,first,second}

# focus the next/previous node
super + {_,shift + }c
    bspc node -f {next,prev}

# focus the next/previous desktop
super + bracket{left,right}
    bspc desktop -f {prev,next}

# focus the last node/desktop
super + {grave,Tab}
    bspc {node,desktop} -f last

# focus the older or newer node in the focus history
super + {o,i}
    bspc wm -h off; \
    bspc node {older,newer} -f; \
    bspc wm -h on

# focus or send to the given desktop
super + {_,shift + }{1-9,0}
    bspc {desktop -f,node -d} '^{1-9,10}'

#
# preselect
#

# preselect the direction
super + ctrl + {h,j,k,l}
    bspc node -p {west,south,north,east}

# preselect the ratio
super + ctrl + {1-9}
    bspc node -o 0.{1-9}

# cancel the preselection for the focused node
super + ctrl + space
    bspc node -p cancel

# cancel the preselection for the focused desktop
super + ctrl + shift + space
    bspc query -N -d | xargs -I id -n 1 bspc node id -p cancel

#
# move/resize
#

# expand a window by moving one of its side outward
super + alt + {h,j,k,l}
    bspc node -z {left -20 0,bottom 0 20,top 0 -20,right 20 0}

# contract a window by moving one of its side inward
super + alt + shift + {h,j,k,l}
    bspc node -z {right -20 0,top 0 20,bottom 0 -20,left 20 0}

# move a floating window
super + {Left,Down,Up,Right}
    bspc node -v {-20 0,0 20,0 -20,20 0}
```

Comment: Actually I only have to run this in my terminal to get it to work: bspc monitor -d 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9. It's like it's not picking it up from the bspwmrc file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chmod +x .config/bspwm/bspwmrc` did the trick